# Futex using boost, threads never wakeup

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, c++14, futex

I am studying about futex synchronisation
Following up the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) , I tried to syncroniaze threads using boost futex
However the threads never wake up

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <boost/fiber/detail/futex.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
void wait(std::atomic<int>  & futexp)
{
    int one = 1;
    while(std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&futexp, &one, 0))
    {}
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "," << futexp.load() << std::endl;
    boost::fibers::detail::futex_wait(&futexp,0);
   // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));

}
void fpost(std::atomic<int>  & futexp)
{
    int zero = 0;
    if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&futexp, &zero, 1)) {
     boost::fibers::detail::futex_wake(&futexp);
    }
}

std::atomic<int>  futexp{1};
int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread>  vec;
    for(int i =0 ; i< 5;++i)
    {
        vec.emplace_back([]()
        {
            wait(futexp);
            fpost(futexp);
        });
    }
    for(auto & el : vec)
    {
        el.join();
    }  
}
```

[Code demo](https://godbolt.org/z/94hMsrW4a)

I am using boost 1.66 and gcc 9.1
What goes wrong with this piece of code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Boost.Fiber` synchronisation primitives for threads, they're only for fibers.  And a general rule for Boost is to avoid using any type in a `detail` namespace; these are implementation details not intended for direct use and should be considered private.  I suggest [reading the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html) if you're curious.

Almost all implementations of the regular `std::mutex` on Linux now use a futex under the hood anyway.